# Compare Name field of two object list without loop

Tags: list, loop, object

I have two Lists(Object) List A has 5 records and List b has 19000 records. What i want to do is compare the name field of list a with that of B. it list b consists of the same name as A, then i want to add it to a 3 rd list. I will not be able to use a nested loop because it is exceeding the time limit. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid nested loops exctract needed names of records to `Set`. After that iterate `listA`, and if `Set` with names contains such name, add that record to `listC`(third list)

```
Set<String> listBNames = new Set<String>();
for(Sobject sobj :listB){
    listBNames.add(sobj.Name);
}
List<Sobject> listC = new List<Sobject>();
for(Sobject sobj :listA){
    if(listBNames.contains(sobj.Name)){
        listC.add(sobj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code after modification listBNames.add((String)sobj.get('Name')); line seems not to be working. it is showing a null list when I print it

Comment: what is an api name of your "name" field? us it

Comment: Its standard name so that should work

Comment: @Rimii i updated my post, can you try it?